# How do I refresh opengl (Java JOGL) display after a specific time interval using Animator?

Tags: java, animation, opengl, jogl

I am trying to rotate a line around a center, and show the rotation using animator in java opengl. I want to make the animation happen faster, i.e. I want to clear the canvas after every .5 seconds. My guess was *setSwapInterval* is doing the trick, but it only takes an integer as a parameter so I can't really change the animation time less than 1 unit.

This should be simple, but I couldn't figure out which parameter is actually controlling the animation time interval.

My global variables:

```
double sec_theta = 0;
```

The animator gets started in the main method:

```
Animator animator = new Animator(canvas);
animator.start();
```

The display method:

```
@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    sec_theta -=6;
    double r = .6;
    double x_center = 0;
    double y_center = 0;
    rotate_line(r,x_center,y_center,r-.1,0,gl);
}
```

This is where the drawing gets done:

```
public void rotate_line(double r,double x_center, double y_center,double sec_x, double sec_y, GL2 gl){
        double radian = Math.toRadians(sec_theta);
        double new_x = sec_x*Math.cos(radian)-sec_y*Math.sin(radian);
        double new_y = sec_x*Math.sin(radian)+sec_y*Math.cos(radian);
        double new_x_center = x_center*Math.cos(radian)-y_center*Math.sin(radian);
        double new_y_center = x_center*Math.sin(radian)+y_center*Math.cos(radian);
        drawHand(new_x_center,new_y_center,new_x,new_y,gl);
    }
public void drawHand(double x_center,double y_center,double end_x, double end_y, GL2 gl){
        gl.glBegin (GL2.GL_LINES);
        gl.glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
        gl.glVertex3d(x_center,y_center, 0);
        gl.glVertex3d(end_x,end_y, 0);
        gl.glEnd();
        gl.glFlush();
    }
```

The init method:

```
@Override
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    drawable.getGL().setSwapInterval(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Swap is not what you think it is. It has to do with the synchronization of the buffer swapping (back to front) with the v-blank.

You can read more [here](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/GLBase.html#setSwapInterval(int)) and [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Swap_Interval).

In general, you want to keep it on if you can render 60fps+, off otherwise.

To implement a canvas clearing every half seconds, you should implement it manually by saving the start time in your `init()`

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

declare the interval you want

```
long interval = 500;
```

and then in your `display()` checking if it's time to update:

```
if(System.currentTimeMillis() - start > interval) {
    ...
}
```

Ps: what you are using is [deprecated Opengl](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL), you should learn current OpenGL.

Comment: Please fix your first link, use the updated Java documentation of our APIs: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/